# What is the interest of duality in algebra, and in general in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, duality-theorems

Before to ask my question I precise I'm a chemist, I ask this question because it makes me crazy to don't understand something I learnt in school.

---

So I had two years ago a small chapter about duality in algebra, and I have never understood the interest of that, and i think all of my classmate too. But (I don't know why) I'm thinking about it for some month, and i'm still lost.

More, in my home I have [this fabulus](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51w7zfIF48L._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg) book writen by Xavier Merlin to help candidat of Polytechnique competitive exam. Unfortunately I'm not in Polytechnique. And even I will "never" use this concept in Chemistry I would like someone explain me why this concept is important in algebra and maybe in all mathematics, and if possible give me an *easy* example which traduce this importance.

I really should be very glad ! :D

---

**NB :**
The autor says in the beginning of the chapter about duality

> We are not sure all persons who have this book (we salute) will have the bravery to read this chapter, due to the aversion they have for this strange phenomenon called duality. It's a pity [...]. Especially as nobody understand it well and in the kingdom of the blind, the one-eyed man is king.

Comment: There must be other applications, but I know duality is an important tool in quantum mechanics.

Comment: An even more practical example, where duality is useful, is the simplex algorithm.

Comment: This may be related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics) There are other types as in:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_principle - I suggest you make your question a bit more specific if possible.

Comment: @EmmadKareem what I learnt was about dual basis.

Comment: In the language of Category Theory, duality is nothing more than changing the direction of arrows(i.e. reversing the direction of a function $X \to Y$ to $Y \to X$). When you have a statement about one category the principal of duality tells you there is automatically a dual concept. To give an example in algebraic topology, the theory of homology is a very algebraic and versatile tool for studying topological spaces, but the dual concept of cohomology is stronger in the sense that it can detect topological differences that homology cannot, if you believe the wiki article.

Comment: @Yeldarbskich, you can certainly appreciate the fact that using «the language of category theory» in this context is pretty absurd, no?

Comment: @Yeldarbskich let me take my aspirin lol

Comment: A very simple example: linear algebra with coordinates. Vectors are $n \times 1$ matrices. Dual vectors are $1 \times n$ matrices. Finite dimensional linear algebra is an unusually simple case, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first approach with duality was in [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)), where it it is a very powerful tool: we can proof a theorem for *points*  and we have a dual theorem for *straight lines* !

But duality is a powerful  tool in many fields of math applications. Also in chemistry I suppose are used [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) that are an example of duality.

There are really many different  case of duality and a first approach can be the use of [duality in logic and  set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)#Duality_in_logic_and_set_theory).

Comment: Thank you very much, I like your example with projective geometry, thats awesome ! :D

Answer (score 3):

It is very often the case that on ehas a vector space $V$ over some field $k$ and one is interested in linear maps $V\to k$. What is more natural that to collect them into a set? Every time we have some objects we are interested in the first thing we do is it collect them in a set. In this case, we write $V^*$ the set of all linear maps $V\to k$.

Now linear maps $V\to k$ can be added and multiplied by scalars. These operations are very natural and it turns out that endowed with them $V^*$ is another vector space.

So $V^*$ is an object that show up naturally when one is interested in linear forms on a vector space $V$, and we are lucky enough that it is itself a vector space.

Duality is the study of this vector space $V^*$ in its relation to the original one $V$.

Comment: Yo ask for «examples where this concept is important» and that is a misguided request, for dual spaces and duality are important in every single context in which vector spaces are important. Making lists of examples where a concept is important is not a good way to undeerstand a concept.

Comment: Someone asked you to make your question more specific, and you mentioned dual bases. Well, if you have a vector space it is almost always useful to have a basis for it. If the vector space you have is $V^*$ for some vector space $V$ this is also the case. Now, $V^*$ is constructed out of $V$ so it is natural to expect that interesting and useful  things in $V$ can be constructed out of the corresponding things in $V$. The existence of dual bases, for example, is simply the observation that that principle does work for bases:.

Comment: I don't want to make a list of examples, I just want to understand this concept in an easy example. And for the moment i'm sorry but it's not the case... :/

Comment: If you want an easy example, take $\mathbb R^2$ and describe its dual space $(\mathbb R^2)^*$ concretely (by describing explictely its elements), take a basis in $\mathbb R^2$ and describe its corresponding dual basis in $(\mathbb R^2)^*$. Do this for a few vector spaces more, like $\mathbb R^3$, the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq3$, etc.

Comment: One does not generally «understand a concept in an easy example». What happens is that you get used to the concept by manipulating it in many, many examples. So do that.

Comment: OK thank you, I will do it, I'll be back in some hours. :)